# Laravel link to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have this menu item such as :

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile') }}"> Profile Managment </a></li>
```

and i want to route that to `ProfileController`. this below my route do not work.

```
Route::resource('profile' , 'ProfileController' , array('as'=>'profile' , 'before'=>'csrf'));
```

i want to route that if user can login and can see profile page and that nust be send all Request to ProfileController.

Error Result:

```
Error in exception handler: Route [profile] not defined. (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/menu.blade.php) in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:207
```

Answer (score 3):

Actualy `Laravel` will create following routes

```
Route(URL)                                      | Name
------------------------------------------------------------------
GET profile                                     | profile.index
GET profile/create                              | profile.create
POST profile                                    | profile.store
GET profile/{profile}                           | profile.show
GET profile/{profile}/edit                      | profile.edit
PUT profile/{profile}                           | profile.update
PATCH profile/{profile}                         |
DELETE profile/{profile}                        | profile.destroy
```

For this

```
Route::resource('profile' , 'ProfileController' , array('as'=>'profile' , 'before'=>'csrf'));
```

If you run `php artisan routes` from your terminal/command prompt then you'll get all the route's list with `name` and `url`.

Comment: my profile view is under view/back_end/layouts and `URL::route('profile.index')` for link to ProfileController with `http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/profile` link. i get this error:`Route [profile.index] not defined.`

Comment: Run `php artisan routes` to be sure you have a route as `profile.index` and also, run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoload class.

Comment: thanks. my form action is `ProfileController@profile` and in ProfileController i have this action:`public function profile(){ print_r(Input::all());}`. i get this error now. `Route [ProfileController@profile] not defined.`

Comment: To submit the form to `store` method you should use `{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'profile.create', 'method' => 'post')) }}` or you may use `action="{{ route('profile.store') }}" method="POST"`.

Comment: If you want to submit the form to the `profile` method then it needs a route.

Comment: thanks after change route to `admin.profile.create` my url changed to `http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/profile/{profile}` and i get this error: `NotFoundHttpException`. My form is: `http://paste.debian.net/79337/`. My Route: `http://paste.debian.net/79339/`

Comment: What you are trying to do, where you want to submit the form, did you use `Form` class of `Laravel`, if not then use it, check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form).

Comment: did you try to see my links? i'm using laravel opening form with Blade. `http://paste.debian.net/79337/`

Comment: Do you have a route named as `admin.profile.update` ?

Comment: my problem is that. why i must be have route? i want to send form to controller directly.i must define route for that?

Comment: This is the easiest way, you can use `url` like `array('url' => 'profile/update/1', 'method' => 'post'))`, this route needs an `id` of the record you want to update.

Comment: With route, `array('route' => array('profile.update', $someModel->id), 'method' => 'post'))`.

Comment: i'm sorry how to fix this route? can you help me? `Route::post('/admin/profile/{id}',array('as'=>'admin.profile.update',function($id){}));  
`

Comment: Sorry! I don't get it, you suppose to use `resource` controller's route according to your question.

Comment: yes. i'm using `Route::resource` and i can not resolve this problem.

Comment: Then you don't need to use `Route::post('/admin/profile/{id}',array('as'=>'admin.profile.update',function($‌​id){}));`, remove it and use the update function inside `ProfileController` for updating and use `{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('profile.update', $someModel->id), 'method' => 'post')) }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll have to:

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile.index') }}"> Profile Managment </a></li>
```

To be sure, execute

```
php artisan routes
```

Laravel will show the list of routes and names you have to use.

Also, you have access to more info in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers